# Setting input method of Emacs on launch

Tags: emacs, dvorak

I have set my default-input-method variable to "english-dvorak":

```
(custom-set-variables
    '(default-input-method "english-dvorak"))
```

When I launch Emacs, this input method is not selected.  How can I make it so that all buffers by default open in this input method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after activate-input-method activate)
  (activate-input-method "english-dvorak"))
```